# Difference between two sample space setups

Tags: probability, combinatorics, intuition

**An ordinary deck of cards is dealt randomly to four players so that each player receives 13 cards.
Find the probability that each player is dealt exactly one ace.**

I was wondering if I could compare this scenario with the following:
Given 4 indistinguishable balls and 4 distinguishable boxes, if we distribute the balls randomly, what is the probability that each box has exactly one ball?
The answer to that is $\frac{1}{4+4-1\choose 4}=\frac{1}{7\choose 4}=\frac{1}{35}$. So is that also the answer to the question above? If not then why?

Comment: Nope.  Entirely different.  In the balls case you're *guaranteed* one ball per box.  For the card case you're not guaranteed one ace per hand.  Entirely different.

Comment: of course! I am really struggling with probability, I've done graduate courses in algebra, took topology, but I am having a lot of trouble with probability :( @DavidG.Stork thanks for the help :)

Comment: Wait a second, no, assume you can put 4 balls in one box!!! @DavidG.Stork

Comment: @Kam I thought that too, but it's not the same.  Since each play gets only $13$ cards, when he gets an Ace it makes it less likely he'll get another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situations are not the same.  It is simplest to consider two cases:

- Case 1:  $16$ cards, including four aces, dealt four cards to each player
- Case 2:  just four aces assigned (in possible multiples) to four players.

In Case 1:  The chance a give player gets all four aces is $\frac{4}{16} \frac{3}{15} \frac{2}{14} \frac{1}{13}$

In Case 2:  $\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{4}$

(The case of $16$ cards is simpler to analyze than $52$, but the principle remains the same.)

The two cases are not the same.

Comment: thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

There are $$\binom{52}{13,13,13,13}=\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}$$ ways to distribute the cards.

We can give each player one Ace in $4!=24$ ways, and then give them each $12$ more cards in $$\binom{48}{12,12,12,12}=\frac{48!}{(12!)^4}$$

Divding gives a probability of $$\frac{24\cdot13^4}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49}\approx.105498$$

Comment: thank you for your time! :)